# Java method complexity

Tags: java, arrays, rest, methods, arguments

recently I've started coding a java library of rest-api of Allegro (e-commerce shop), to use it in further projects.

I've encountered that some things like getting offers by parameters is pretty difficult to me from the aspect of complexity.

Basically there are [multiple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mu1VW.png) query parameters that people can use to find offers in that service.

Is there any possibility to make an universal method that can take x number of parameters (I'm not talking about String... etc.), and process them without specifying which argument is to which parameter?

Example:

Seller.Id (as only argument), or Seller.ID and limit which is gonna mess the argument order.

I want to mention that I was considering making multiple method but with another arguments that the method takes in, but taking 12 different arguments and combinations of them would make a lot of mess.

Also, I want to apologize if any of the terminology is incorrect (foreign language).

Comment: Have you considered using some kind of `List` or `Map`?

Comment: `public Offers getOffers(QueryParameters queryParameters)` where `QueryParameters` has some [builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) that allows nullable fields. A caller would look like `shop.getOffers(QueryParameters.builder().phrase("foo").searchMode(SearchMode.Regular).build());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce this complexity by grouping the parameters into separate objects. For instance, you could group

1. seller.id, seller.login into SellerInfo object
2. category, phrase, searchmode, offset and limit into SearchInfo object

Using objects as parameters would help even in future, if in case you need to add/remove parameters, you would not need to change the method definition, rather the attributes inside the objects.

Using a Hashmap is another option. However, that will increase the overhead of managing key/value pairs. This is a good option if you do not want to create additional custom objects suggested in the first option.

Comment: Thanks, it really helped me. Fun fact, this project is mostly created on objects due to nested jsons.

Comment: Glad it helped :)
Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a class (DTO) with this arguments as attributes. Put only this class as argument to you method (POST or PUT). For GET or DELETE use only an ID number...